# Puedo usar interfaces( models) en formulario reactivo con formBuilder, en angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, angular9

He visto varios tutoriales donde si se puede usar interfaces en formularios reactivos que usan FormControl y FormGroup, pero se puede usar interfaces cuando se usa FormBuilder? . Favor podrían mostrar como seria la estructura en el archivo : (... component.ts)

Comment: Hola Oscar, si se puede, ten en cuenta que creas las interfaces para poder acceder a las propiedades de ese objeto, depende del contexto de tu proyecto puedes ver si es factible crear un model o crear variables en el scope de tu ts

Comment: Oscar puedes poner un ejemplo más concreto? Que es lo quieres hacer?